# Laravel Eloquent - Count the number of rows and pluck/include a column to the resulting array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables which is `sales_d`, `products` and `categories`.

A `sales_d` belongs to `products` model/table. 
`id_product` will serve as the relation ship column to the `products` table.
`product_id` in `products` table

[image]

A `products` belongs to a `categories` model/table.
`product_type` will serve as the relation ship column to the `categories` table
`category_id` in the `categories` table

[image]

And lastly the `categories` table.

[image]

**Now I successfully counted the the rows with these code:**

```
 $DateToday = date('yy-m-d');
    $categories = Category::all()->where('category_status', '=', '1');
    $categoriesCounter = [];

    //Get all ID of products
    $data = SalesD::select('id_product')
            ->whereDate('date_order', '=', $DateToday)
            ->orderBy('date_order', 'asc')
            ->get();

    for($x=0; $x<count($categories); $x++)
    {
    
        $product = Product::find($data[$x]->id_product);   

        //COUNTS THE ROWS OF PRODUCTS BY CATEGORY ID 

        $categoriesCounter[$x] = SalesD::with(['category'], 'category_id', $product->product_type)
                            ->select('category_name')
                            ->where('id_product', '=', $product->product_id)
                            ->whereDate('date_order', '=', $DateToday)
                            ->count();
    }
```

Here's the result of the code above:

[image]

The results inside the array is the number of **products that matched the category ID**.

**The problem is that I want to include the `category_name` in the array**. This will be the objective output or something like this (still an array):

```
array:9 [▼
0 => 'total': 1, 'category_name': 'Milk Tea'
  1 => 'total': 4, 'category_name': 'Cheese Cake'
  2 => 'total': 2, 'category_name': 'Salty Cream Cheese'
  3 => 'total': 4, 'category_name': 'Fruit Tea'
  4 => 'total': 2, 'category_name': 'Milk Shake'
  5 => 'total': 4, 'category_name': 'Food'
  6 => 'total': 1, 'category_name': 'Yakult'
  7 => 'total': 1, 'category_name': 'Fruit Shakes'
  8 => 'total': 2, 'category_name': 'Scramble'
]
```

Am I on the right track of achieving it or do I need to change the entire code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do some steps to simplify your code :

1- Add a **hasManyThrough** relation to **Category Model** like this :

```
public function product_sales()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        SalesD::class,
        Product::class,
        "product_type" // Foreign key on products table
        , "id_product" // Foreign key on sales_d table
        , "category_id" // Primary key on categories table
        , "product_id" // Primary key on products table
    )
        ->whereDate("sales_d.date_order", now())
        ->orderBy("sales_d.date_order");
}
```

*Don't forget to import these models **Product***,**SalesD**

[You can see the description in here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

2- Now You can use **withCount()** function :

```
$categories = Category::where('category_status', '=', '1')->withCount("product_sales")->get();
```

Comment: Great! Works perfectly! :)

Comment: How can I do this same method that you posted above If I want to count or get the sum of the 'product_selling_price' by each product_type / category?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no native function to do this. Check out this [package](https://github.com/Alexmg86/laravel-sub-query)  It will add some useful functions like **withSum()** to do the trick